# I want different forms according to share_type choices field without submitting the form, how can i do it in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
SHARE_TYPE = (('SECONDARY ', 'secondary'),
          ('IPO', 'IPO'),
          ('RIGHT', 'Right'),
          ('BONUS', 'Bonus'),

          )

class PurchasedShare(models.Model):
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    transaction_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    broker = models.ForeignKey(Broker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    share_type = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=SHARE_TYPE)
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shareholder = models.ForeignKey(ShareHolder, 
                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.symbol)
```

For eg, if i select IPO share_type, then create forms having fields 
 symbol,quantity,rate and portfolio only and if i select secondary 
 share_type create forms having all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create a first form step where you ask only for the share type, then direct to a page like `/new-purchased-share/?share_type=SECONDARY` that gets the right form and displays it.
2. Use Javascript to show/hide the previous form fields depending on the share type selected.

Comment: could you please show  me the example that you have done or any reference as you described in options 2 ?